# Umbraco : using property editors in front-end

Tags: razor, umbraco, umbraco7

Do you know about some tutorial on how to use umbraco property editors in frontend ? I am creating a page where member can edit his profile photo and I need an Image cropper control like the one in backoffice so he can crop the image. Any ideas ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Umbraco Property editors are not created for use in the front-end.  For front-end you can use standard (javascript) components you like.

If you like the imagecropper in the umbraco back-end, you can investigate the [propertyeditors source code at github](https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/tree/7.2.0/src/Umbraco.Web/PropertyEditors) to see how they have implemented this.